# MySQL - Finding how much duplicates are inside the same table given

Tags: mysql

Considering I have the following two sets of rows (same type) in a WHERE clause:

```
A   B
1   1
2   2
3   4
```

I need to find how many A is in B
For example, for the given table above, it would be 66% since 2 out of 3 numbers are in B

Another example:

```
A   B
1   1
2   2
3   4
    5
    3
```

Would give 100% since all of the numbers in A are in B

Here is what I tried myself: (Doesn't work on all test cases..)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getProductsByDate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE getProductsByDate (IN d_given date)
BEGIN
SELECT 
    Product,
    COUNT(*) AS 'total Number',
    (SELECT 
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Part) FROM products WHERE Product=B.Product) - COUNT(*)
        FROM
            products AS b2
        WHERE
            b2.SOP < B.SOP AND b2.Part != B.Part) AS 'New Parts',
             CONCAT(round((SELECT 
            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Part) FROM products WHERE Product=B.Product) - COUNT(*)
        FROM
            products AS b2
        WHERE
            b2.SOP < B.SOP AND b2.Part != B.Part)/count(DISTINCT part)*100, 0), '%') as 'Share New'
FROM
    products AS B
WHERE
    b.SOP < d_given
GROUP BY Product;

END//

DELIMITER ;
CALL getProductsByDate (date("2018-01-01"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Go on. Try something!

Comment: @Strawberry told you first try someting by yourself and ask your question again with the query you tried and what the output is of that query.

Comment: I already tried myself and experienced difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming your tables TA and TB respectively you could try something like this (test made on MSSQL and Mysql at moment)

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(PERC) ,4)AS PERC_TOT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TA.ID , 1.00/ (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM TA) AS PERC
    FROM TA 
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TB  WHERE TB.ID=TA.ID)
    ) C;
```

Output with your first sample data set:

```
PERC_TOT
0,6667
```

Output with your second sample data set:

```
PERC_TOT
1,0000
```

**Update (I made the original for two tables, as I was thinking at solution).**  This is for one single table (is almost the same than the former query): (I used ID1 for column A and ID2 for column B)

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(PERC) ,4)AS PERC_TOT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TA.ID1 , 1.00/ (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID1) FROM TA) AS PERC
    FROM TA 
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT ID2 FROM TA AS TB  WHERE TB.ID2=TA.ID1)
    ) C;
```

Comment: I still continue to think that negative votes are wrong and anachronistic habit  in stackoverflow and that they are not correct and that they are not made by honor men.

Comment: No offense meant, but this is just my opinion why someone down voted your answer. He was asked to try something first and put some effort to try to solve his problem, but instead you gave an instant solution where he can just copy and paste and just make a few changes or maybe not. If you think you are helping him grow or helping him solve his problem by just giving a solution without giving his part of the bargain. I call this spoon feeding. Anyway I have up voted your answer, you may hate it, but that is my opinion and observation.

Comment: I don't need help to grow. I already did try myself and experienced difficulties.